# Running 'Append Query' from EXCEL-VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010, vba

I have created an 'Append Query' in Access 2010, with a set of criteria and set number of records are created. However, when I run the same 'Append Query' from EXCEL-VBA I get a different number of records?

Comment: what's your sql?

Comment: It's because of reason(s) that this is happening. If you give us more information, like your append query and the VBA I can almost definitely elaborate. If the append is getting data from other tables, then we may need some sample data from those tables to understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve the problem. The issue was using 'Wildcards' in the criteria. In Access 2010 you use the star symbol "*", however, if you run the Access Query from EXCEL-VBA you need to change the wildcard to a percent symbol "%" instead.

Example: Not Like "Engla*" needs to be Not Like "Engla%".